# General approach to check if the given function is NOT a valid kernel

Tags: reproducing-kernel-hilbert-spaces

In general, for proving that the given kernel function *is* valid, I try one of the following two approaches:

Check if the gram matrix is Symmetric Postive Semi Definite.

Check if the kernel function can be expressed in terms of other functions by using closure properties of kernels.

Can someone highlight general approaches or methods for proving that a given function is NOT a valid kernel function?

If both of the above approaches fail, what else should one try and how does one conclude that the given function is not a valid kernel function?

Comment: It might be clearer if you stated exactly what you meant by "kernel function".

Comment: @kimchilover I am talking about the kernel trick - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method